# How to explain "tff.to_type((tf.int64, [2]))"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I am learning Tensorflow-Federated, while I don't know how to explain the syntax `tff.to_type((tf.int64, [2]))`. I consider `tff.to_type` can create a tff data type, but I don't know the meaning of [2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `tff.to_type` creates a `tff` type with the dtype `tf.int64` and the shape `[2]`. It is like defining a `tf.TensorSpec` that describes the properties of a tensor. It has a `shape` argument as well as a `dtype` argument. For better understanding, run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[2])
```

```
TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)
```

This tensor will, therefore, have two values with the data type `tf.int64`.

Comment: In my opinion, the shape [2] means two separate numbers, is it?

Comment: What do you mean two separate numbers? @atcw108

Comment: I means [2] is a representation of the dtype include two amounts of value, such as array[1,2]